# [Choosing tunable parameter M in Golomb/Rice Encoding]

Tags: algorithms, information-theory, data-compression

I am a Computer Science student and I study Data Compression now. I read many methods but Golomb-Rice Encoding was not clear for me.  I understand the method how it works but in the algorithm there is 'Tunable parameter $M$' that operates with the number that you want to encode. My question is how can I decide what value of $M$ to use? Is there a optimal solution for deciding $M$?

Comment: Have you checked the obvious sources, such as your textbook or [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golomb_coding) and the references given there?

Comment: I checked but did i miss something in Wikipedia ? And yes i currently read Handbook of Data Compression-David Salomon&Giovanni Motta.

Comment: Well, Wikipedia states good values of $M$ for several scenarios.